# Detecting Bluetooth SPP serial port disconnect (C# 4.5, Windows 8.1)

Tags: c#, windows, bluetooth

C# application using .NET 4.5 running on Windows 8.1

Classic Bluetooth device connects and uses SPP, using Microsoft Bluetooth stack only. Device is paired prior starting the application (the application is not involved in pairing and thinks its a real serial port).

Application connects to the SPP COM port using C# SerialPort class.

All works OK, until...

Bluetooth device is powered off, but...
SerialPort.IsConnected still reports true (for at least a minute).

I've tried hooking the main form's WndProc and trapping WM_DEVICECHANGE, but while I see messages for USB devices coming and going, no message is generated after the Bluetooth device is powered off.

Anybody know how to get PROMPT and ACCURATE information about the connection?

Thanks!

Best Regards, Dave

Comment: does the device send a "I'm going for a nap now" message to the host? if it just cuts power and vanishes, then there's no way for the host to know it's gone until it fails to respond to a message. it'd be no different than the device going out-of-range - communications simply stop.

Comment: I have had to handle this before. Because this is a virtual com device it stays paired even though the device went away. The device needs to send out a message when connected and the application need to monitor for loss of that connection.